# SQL: Finding maximum values with join and joining additional values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a "table-a" with customers and a "table-b" with customer contacts. I would like to **select each customer** and **display the last "customer contact by phone"** and the **last "customer visit"**, alongside with some **info from table-b**.

The table design is as follows:

### table-a:

```
number (PK) Name    Adress      
101         Bob     Street 1      
102         Peter   Street
```

### table-b:

```
number (PK) c-nr (FK)   type    date        free text
11111       101         visit   01.08.2016  text3     
11112       101         visit   20.08.2016  text2     
11113       102         phone   15.09.2016  text1     
11113       102         email   15.09.2016  text1
```

### And I would like to query as follows:

```
Number Name     Adress      Last Visit  Visit Text  Last-Call   Call-Text
101    Bob      Street  1   20.08.2016  text2       NONE        NONE                  
102    Peter    Street  2   NONE        NONE        15.09.206   text1
```

### What I got so far is:

```
select
a.number
,a.name
,a.adress
,last-visit.date
,last-call.date
from table-a as a
left join 
    (select
    inner-b.c-nr as customer-number
    ,max(inner-b.date) as date
    from table-b as inner-b
    where
    type = 'visit'
    group by innner-b.c-nr) as last-visit on last-visit.customer-number = a.number
left join 
    (select
    inner-b.c-nr as customer-number
    ,max(inner-b.date) as date
    from table-b as inner-b
    where
    type = 'phone'
    group by inner-b.c-nr) as last-call on last-call.customer-number = a.number
```

### Call for help:

It works so far as it will show me the last visit and last call, but i can't get to the point that i can add the text, because if i add other fields (i.e. the primary key or the text itself) in the inner select it will mess up the group by. Also, i am not sure this is "good SQL".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your two subqueries are returning the exact same thing? Is that a typo? It would be a lot easier to help if you could set up a sql fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Hi, sorry, the 1st querry returns visits, the 2nd querry should return the calls. Edited. I'll look into sqlfiddle.

Comment: A couple of notes: try to avoid punctuation in a field name where possible, keep an eye on date formats and keep aliases nice and short

Answer (score 2):

You can use OUTER APPLY to get latest `visit`, `phone` event:

```
SELECT  a.number,
        a.[Name],
        a.Adress,
        CASE WHEN b.[type] = 'visit' THEN b.[date] ELSE NULL END as [Last Visit],
        CASE WHEN b.[type] = 'visit' THEN b.[free text] ELSE NULL END as [Visit Text],
        CASE WHEN c.[type] = 'phone' THEN c.[date] ELSE NULL END as [Last-Call],
        CASE WHEN c.[type] = 'phone' THEN c.[free text] ELSE NULL END as [Call-Text]
FROM tableA a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM TableB
    WHERE [c-nr] = a.number and [type] IN ('visit' )
    ORDER BY [date] desc
) b
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM TableB
    WHERE [c-nr] = a.number and [type] IN ('phone')
    ORDER BY [date] desc
) c
```

Output for sample you provided:

```
number  Name    Adress      Last Visit  Visit Text  Last-Call   Call-Text
101     Bob     Street 1    20.08.2016  text2       NULL        NULL
102     Peter   Street      NULL        NULL        15.09.2016  text1
```

Comment: Ty. Ther's so much to learn! Three answers, and all will do the job.

Comment: This won't work if one person has a call and a visit on different dates.

Comment: @Harper My pleasure to help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need row_number in your life:

```
select a.number, 
       a.name, 
       a.Address,
       b.date as CallDate, 
       b.freetext as CallNotes, 
       c.date as VisitDate, 
       c.freetext as VisitNotes
from TableA a
left join 
    (
        select c_nr, date, freetext, row_number() over(partition by c_nr order by date desc) as Call_Ord
        from TableB
        where type = 'Phone'
    ) b
    on a.number = b.c_nr
    and b.Call_Ord = 1
left join 
    (
        select c_nr, date, freetext, row_number() over(partition by c_nr order by date desc) as Call_Ord
        from TableB
        where type = 'Visit'
    ) c
    on a.number = c.c_nr
    and c.Vis_Ord = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/VHZ57243)

```
WITH lastVisit as (
      SELECT [c-nr], date, [free text],
             row_number() over (partition by [c-nr] order by [date] desc) rn
      FROM table_b
      WHERE type = 'visit'
 ), lastCall as (
      SELECT [c-nr], date, [free text],
             row_number() over (partition by [c-nr] order by [date] desc) rn
      FROM table_b
      WHERE type = 'phone'
 )
 SELECT ta.[number], ta.Name, ta.[Adress],
        COALESCE(lv.date, 'NONE') as [Last Visit],
        COALESCE(lv.[free text], 'NONE') as [Visit Text],

        COALESCE(lc.date, 'NONE') as [Last Call],
        COALESCE(lc.[free text], 'NONE') as [Call Text]

 FROM table_a ta
 LEFT JOIN lastVisit lv
   ON ta.[number] = lv.[c-nr]
  AND lv.rn = 1
 LEFT JOIN lastCall lc
   ON ta.[number] = lc.[c-nr]
  AND lc.rn = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Ty! Never heard of Coalesce, i'll look into it!

Comment: check update, I include a demo and fix some sintaxis errors